# svn - get a history of folders created in the root of a repository

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn, svnadmin

I plan to dump the svn **Fruit** repository in order to exclude a set of folders from the root of it then load it again. For e.g.

```
Fruit
-Banana
-Tomato
-Potato
```

So we know **Fruit** is the svn project and I want to filter exclude some vegetables entered by mistake. Potato is obvious enough but I'm sure that there are folders from previous revisions that I would also like to exclude.

How can I get a full history of the folders that existed in the root of the **Fruit** repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the *history*, or do you want a listing of all the *current* folders?

#### Lists current folders under the `Fruit` repo directory.

```
$ svn ls http://svn/repo/Fruit
```

#### History of all files and folders *directly* under the `Fruits` repository directory.

```
$ svn log --depth=immediates http://svn/repos/Fruit
```

Or, are you trying to *filter* out the repo via *svndumpfilter*? That's an entirely different question...

Comment: Using the log, I'll be able to identify all the folders that ever existed under the Fruit repository then I can filter them as I wish. I couldn't exclude before because they aren't current and thus I don't know their names. Thank you